# AppSheet. How to create a view for different users

Tags: android, view

I'm trying to help a friend on making an AppSheet app, and in the app I need to make views for each users, basically a user can only view the rows of the table that he added to the table.

From what I've read, we can make views with the `show_if` statement, basically there is a column named `user`, which will have the email of the user that added the row.

I want to make a view for each user, to see only the rows they've added to the app, I know we have to use something like,

```
show_if USEREMAIL() = column.user, show row...
```

or something like this, but have no idea on how to make the expression and also, change the expression for the admin user to have access to all rows, and I don't even know where to insert this expression

Thank you, every help will be appreciated

Comment: Changed appsheet to AppSheet 'cause it's the name of technology
Fixed some spelling and formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using Slices or Security Filters.

Also, next time consider asking questions in the AppSheet community: https://community.appsheet.com/. 
This way you'll probably won't have to wait 4 months for someone to address your question.